# How can I declare a generic HashMap in a Rust struct?

Tags: rust

The usual way to declare a HashMap in a Rust struct is as follows:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  query: HashMap<String, String>,
  counter: u32,
}
```

How would I write the above code if I do not know what the HashMap would contain beforehand? I have tried the below code without success.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  query: HashMap<K, V>,
  counter: u32,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add your generics to your struct declaration as well:

```rust
struct MyStruct<K,V> {
  query: HashMap<K, V>,
  counter: u32,
}
```

Have a look at [Rust Book/Generic Data Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-struct-definitions)